# How can I create complex types in suds python

Tags: python, wsdl, suds

How can I create complex types and how to pass the values in the complex type,how to call them.

Below is the transferBalance method which take complex types

```
(TransferBalance){
  transDetails = 
  (MoneyTransfer){
     transferDate = None
     debitAccount = None
     creditAccount = None
     transferAmount = None
  }
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the factory:

```
MT = client.factory.create('MoneyTransfer')
MT.transferDate = '01/01/01'
MT.debitAccount = '01234567'
MT.creditAccount = '87654321'
MT.transferAmount = 1000000.00

TB = client.factory.create('TransferBalance')
TB.transDetails = MT
```